# Jfrog Remote repository with multiple contexts paths

Tags: artifactory, artifact, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

In jfrog remote repository, Can we have a single remote repo to resolve multiple paths of the remote repo urls?

for example, I need to create a single repo in jfrog, where as all the below paths of the remote repo is accessible to browse.

```
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/ 
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/addons/x86_64
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/x86_64
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/addons/x86_64/repodata/
https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/optional/latest/x86_64/repodata/
```

Tried with remote repo pointing to "https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/: but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single remote pointing to "https://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/" but since the local repo config file (/etc/yum.repos.d/my.repo) should point to the path of the repodata folder you will need to have several configuration files each of them pointing to a different path.
So for the first two repositories you mentioned, you can have the following two local conf files:

latest.conf:

```
[latest]
name=latest
baseurl=http://admin:password@my-jfrog-url/artifactory/rpm-remote/latest/x86_64/
```

addons.conf

```
[addons]
name=addons
baseurl=http://admin:password@my-jfrog-url/artifactory/rpm-remote/addons/x86_64
```

The above conf files point to the same repository but each file to a different path.

Comment: i tried with 2 different remote  repositories in Jfrog and looped them inside a virtual repo. So the team can use the same endpoint for resolving the packages from the both "/latest/" and "/optional"